# Centering a scrollpane in a scene when window resized

Tags: java, javafx

Hi I have a ScrollPane with a GridPane as it's child,

```
ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(grid);
        Scene scene = new Scene(scroll);
```

Does anyone know how to center the items of a ScrollPane in the scene even when the window is resized?

Comment: use VBox to center the ScrollPane

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to center the content of the `ScrollPane` when the content is smaller than the viewport. This is not as straightforward as simply using a layout which centers its children as the content. A `ScrollPane`, by default, only sizes its content to said content's preferred size but aligns the content with the top-left corner. This means the content, when smaller than the viewport, only consumes the space in the top-left corner; even if the content centers its own children, the area of the content is not equal to the area of the viewport, thus the content is not centered within the viewport.

It would be nice if `ScrollPane` had an "alignment" property to customize this behavior. Since no such property exists you have to configure the `ScrollPane` to fill its viewport while also allowing the content to grow beyond the viewport's dimensions. Then you just need to use a layout which centers its children or can be configured to do so—`GridPane` is one such layout. Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // create and populate GridPane
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(10);
    gridPane.setVgap(10);
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gridPane.add(rectangle, col, row);
      }
    }

    /*
     * From the property's Javadoc: "The alignment of the grid within
     * the gridpane's width and height".
     *
     * Using Pos.CENTER makes the GridPane center its grid when the GridPane
     * has extra horizontal and/or vertical space.
     */
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    /*
     * Forces the dimensions of the GridPane to be at least the same
     * as its preferred size. This prevents the GridPane from shrinking
     * due to the fit-to-width/fit-to-height configuration of the
     * ScrollPane.
     */
    gridPane.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(gridPane);

    /*
     * Forces the content of the ScrollPane to have the same dimensions
     * as the viewport. However, because of the min-size configuration above,
     * the GridPane can never be smaller than its preferred size. This means
     * the ScrollPane will grow its content to fit the viewport but won't
     * shrink its content to fit the viewport.
     */
    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
    scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

Note that, depending on your use case, you may not need to configure the min-size of the content to be the same as its preferred size.